# Button created by jQuery isn't recognized

Tags: jquery, button

Inside one of my jQuery functions I create a button with id "one" , using `$(some div).html(<button>...</button>)`. The problem is that when I later use `$("#one").click(function(){....})`, it's not working. the button is not recognized. 
Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Use .on instead of .click, like

```
 $(body).on('click', '#one', function() {.....});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button is dynamically generated in the code, and thus goes unidentified by the click event handler, as it wasn't a part of the DOM when you binded the event. use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) - i.e bind the event to a permanent DOM object, such as the `document`, and delegate it down to your button :

```
$(document).on("click","#one",function(){
// Your code
});
```